# How to read "Table of Contents" from MS Word Document using win32com client?

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

Recently i have started working on python and MS word. I tried to update the Table of contents in a .docx document using win32com.client python module(pywin32).

```
def update_toc(docx_file):
word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(docx_file)
doc.TablesOfContents(1).Update()
print(doc.TablesOfContents)
doc.Close(SaveChanges=True)
word.Quit()
```

Now i am trying to look how to read the updated Table of Contents using win32com.client

Q1: Please share your suggestions or references on how to read the Table of Contents.

Q2: In the above code block doc.Close(SaveChanges=True) takes around 35 secs to perform the task. Is there any performance improvement in the Close block we can achieve?

**Update (inputs from @DS_London):**

To read the Table of Contents

```
doc.TablesOfContents(1).Range()
```

The above code returns the Table of Contents as a single String.

Comment: The `TableOfContents` object has a `.Range` property which returns a Word Range. This range has a `.Text` property ... I haven't tried this, but it might be a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and time @DS_London .... I have updated the same working code above